# How to include parameters inside 'SqlCommand' sentence and after set theirs values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters

I have next SQL Server command working: (it inserts data into a table)

```
try
        {
            // Open conn
            conexion.Open();
            // New trans
            SqlTransaction transaccion = conexion.BeginTransaction();
            // Command
            SqlCommand comandoAEjecutar = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = conexion,
                Transaction = transaccion,
                CommandText = @"
                            INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_battery]
                                ([capacity], [description], [image], [price]) 
                            VALUES 
                                (@capacity, @description, @fileContent, @price)
                            "
            };

            int capacity = 50;
            string descr = "Funciona2";
            float price = 70;
            string path = @"C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Ingeniería Informática\2 año\2º Cuatrimestre\Programación Visual Avanzada\ProyectoFinal\AJMobile\AJMobile\src\images\Battery\baterry_4000.png";
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters.Add("@capacity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = capacity;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = descr;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters.Add("@fileContent", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = fileContent;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Float).Value = price;

            int numeroFilasAfectadas = comandoAEjecutar.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As you can see, I have added parameters and theirs values out of `SqlCommand` statement. I want to include parameters inside this statement and after set theirs values, somethig like:

```
try
        {
            // Open conn
            conexion.Open();
            // New trans
            SqlTransaction transaccion = conexion.BeginTransaction();
            // Command
            SqlCommand comandoAEjecutar = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = conexion,
                Transaction = transaccion,
                CommandText = @"
                            INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_battery]
                                ([capacity], [description], [image], [price]) 
                            VALUES 
                                (@capacity, @description, @fileContent, @price)
                            ",
                Parameters =
                {
                    // I wanna set their types too
                    "@capacity" as SqlDbType.Int,
                    "@description" as SqlDbType.VarChar,
                    "@fileContent" as SqlDbType.VarBinary,
                    "@price" as SqlDbType.Float
                }
            };


            int capacity = 50;
            string descr = "Funciona2";
            float price = 70;
            string path = @"C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\Ingeniería Informática\2 año\2º Cuatrimestre\Programación Visual Avanzada\ProyectoFinal\AJMobile\AJMobile\src\images\Battery\baterry_4000.png";
            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

            // Add values to parameters
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters["@capacity"].Value = capacity;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters["@description"].Value = descr;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters["@fileContent"].Value = fileContent;
            comandoAEjecutar.Parameters["@price"].Value = price;

            int numeroFilasAfectadas = comandoAEjecutar.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Exists anyway to do that? I have been tryed many ways but I could not achieve that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add objects to a collection, so you need the appropriate Collection Initialiser pattern.

```
    Parameters =
    {
        new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@capacity", DbType = DbType.Int32, Value = capacity},
        new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@description", DbType = DbType.String, Value = descr},
        new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@fileContent", DbType = DbType.Binary, Value = fileContent},
        new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@price", DbType = DbType.Decimal, Value = price}
    }
```

This will see to making sure the Command object has the parameters added as you expect them later on

Comment: "and their values"

Comment: Ok, thank you JayV! This works fine. Is there any way of including values inside too? Something like: `Parameters =
    {
        new SqlParameter("@capacity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 67,
    }`

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you for pointing out my mistake, updated the answer to include the setting of the value

Comment: @JuMoGar I have updated the answer to show how to include the Value as well

Comment: @JayV Ok, Thank you again!